# Is there a way to "layer" a Javascript event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onkeypress

I have a set of 3 rows of 12 `input[class='variant-amount']` boxes each. Some of the input fields have an event associated with them such as `"onkeypress"` or `"onkeyup"`

I would like to apply a global event listener on `.variant-amounts` using the `"onkeypress"` event, but I would not like to override the action of those input fields that have already attached a `"onkeypress"` event.

So, is there a way to basically set up an event that when occurs it executes its own code and after executes its own `"onkeypress"` event? (without modifying any input box itself, they must be accessed though its class)

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Your selectors suggest you are, and it would change everything

Comment: It's just demonstrative, I am using JavaScript but I wouldn't mind to use jquery. Best performance is the option.

Comment: @mkmnstr There's nothing jQuery-specific about these DOM selectors

Answer (score 0):

```
function all(){ // code }
function press(){ 
  //code
  all();
}
function up(){ 
  // code 
  all();
}
elemenUp.addEventListener("keyup", up);
elementPress.addEventListener("keypress", press);
```

If at any point you have to access this, just make an argument in `all(argThis)` and pass this inside event listeners functions.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the functionality of an event handler and also extend it you have to override the event handler but store a reference to the original one and invoke it.

I recommend you assign the global event handler after each `input` has been assigned the specific one, do something like this after all inputs have their handlers:

```
// Query all the inputs and transform the result into a proper array
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[class="variant-amount"]'))
    .forEach(function (variantAmount) {
        var original = variantAmount.onkeypress;

        variantAmount.onkeypress = function () {
            // do your stuff

            // Call the original event handler forwarding both this and the arguments, which needs to be converted to a real array
            original.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        };
    });
```

Comment: You can just use **`[]`** instead of **`Array.prototype`**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe container for keypress event in capturing phase. 
This way your container will receive keypress before its children:

```js
var body = document.body;
// add handler of keypress in capturing phase
body.addEventListener("keypress", function(){ console.log("keypress body") }, true);

var input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(){ console.log("keypress input") });
```

```html
<div>
  <input value="foo" >
</div>
```

Just in case you've missed that capturing/bubbling principle of event propagation on DOM : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html